# Открыть ссылку iframe в новой вкладке

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, link

В iframe:

```
<iframe id="emailHtml" sandbox="allow-top-navigation" src="GetMessageBody?id=1261&amp;msgType=1">
</iframe>
```

есть ссылка:

```
<a target="_top" href="/admin/helpdesk/GetFileToOpen?id=14">аудио лекции.png</a>
```

При клике на ссылку загружается и открывается изображение.

Нужно, чтобы изображение открылось в новой вкладке.

Сейчас у тега < a> установлен атрибут target="_top" и изображение открывается в текущей вкладке.

Пробовал у тега < a> устанавливать разные значения атрибуту target (_blank, _new, _parent), но изображение либо вообще не открывается, либо открывается в текущей вкладке.

Так же пробовал устанавливать тег **base** у **iframe**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037839/how-to-force-link-from-iframe-to-be-opened-in-the-parent-window

Какие еще могут быть варианты?

Comment: По идее с _blank всё должно работать, покажите, пожалуйста, исходный код.

Comment: а вы `base` добавляли в `head` `iframe`-а?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин да. Но, кажется, неправильно: я это тестил добавляя тег в head уже на странице в браузере, а не в коде при генерации iframe

Comment: Проверьте - не блокирует ли браузер новые окна

Comment: @НикитаПавлов Вы отчасти правы. С  _blank работает, но если убрать атрибут sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Помогло избавление от атрибута sandbox в iframe.

В моем случае контент подгружается из проверенного источника, поэтому отсутствие атрибута не критично. Допускаю такое решение как временное.